# Laravel validator messages, iterating in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Laravel gives back the messages below when my form is submitted without any values being filled out.

I do `return json_encode(array('validation' => $validator->messages());`

In my JS file my jQuery does `var result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result));`

How can I then iterate over this JSON to print out each error one by one?

```
{
    "validation": {
        "username_c": [
            "The username c field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ],
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
        "password_repeat": [
            "The password repeat field is required."
        ],
        "first_name": [
            "The first name field is required."
        ],
        "last_name": [
            "The last name field is required."
        ],
        "rsa": [
            "The rsa field is required."
        ],
        "rc": [
            "The rc field is required."
        ],
        "rz": [
            "The rz field is required."
        ],
        "op": [
            "The op field is required."
        ],
        "dp": [
            "The dp field is required."
        ],
        "mp": [
            "The mp field is required."
        ],
        "bd": [
            "The bd field is required."
        ],
        "tc": [
            "The tc must be accepted."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier if you parse your result as JSON `JSON.parse(result)` (or in face have Laravel return the result as JSON to you using `Response::json(result)`.

Then use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) :

```
$.each(result.validation, function(key, value){
    // Each of you error, do something here
    console.log('Error [' + key + ']' + ' : ' + value);
});
```

The above prints the error to your console.